# What are ways to improve attack modifier in D&D 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e

In D&D 4e, it seems you have very few ways to improve your attack modifier.

- Improve the attribute the attack is based on.  This can only be done via level increases.
- Improve the magic of the weapon.

Are there any other ways to improve my character's chances to hit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design there are very few ways to permanently increase your attack modifier.

[Weapon Expertise](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1032)<sup>DDI</sup> and other related expertise feats is the prime way.  Certain Paragon Paths such as [Kensei](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=21)<sup>DDI</sup> help too.

Other than those limited areas, you need to work with your party to maximise temporary bonuses

- Combat advantage is the big one
- Make critters prone (to gain Combat advantage)
- Lots of powers give temporary bonuses
- The warlord specializes in letting others attack with considerable bonuses.

Comment: Cleric abilities give bonuses too.

Answer (score 4):

For implement users who take the  **Superior Implement Training** feat in PHB3, there are several *superior implement properties* (on page 195) that can increase attack bonuses. It requires you to take a feat (*Superior Implement Training* which lets you use **one** type of superior implement) and the materials cost (slightly) more than the standard object.

There is the **Accurate** property, for example, on the *Accurate Rod* and *Accurate Orb*:

> **Accurate**: You gain a +1 bonus to
>   attack rolls  made with an accurate
>   implement.

For implements users who have a number of powers attacking the same defense (Ref, Will, or Fort), there are also properties like the **Undeniable** property:

> **Undeniable**: You gain a +1 bonus to
>   attack rolls  against Will when
>   attacking with  an undeniable 
>   implement.

(There is also **Unerring** for Ref and **Unstoppable** for Fort.)

These three properties are often paired up with another, as in the superior implement **Crystal Orb**:

```
Name          gp   wt  properties
------------------------------
Crystal orb   27   2   Energized (psychic), undeniable
```

where **Energized(psychic)** increases the damage of powers with the psychic keyword.

Answer (score 2):

One way is through the selection of feats which improve your character's attack modifier in limited circumstances. Then, take powers which capitalize or provoke those circumstances regularly. For example, a Fighter with a high Wisdom might combine Blade Opportunist with the Combat Superiority class feature and exploits that add or replace opportunity attacks.

Comment: Can you give examples?

Comment: @C. Ross: Edited to add.